# "Save as single web page" on Firefox

Tags: firefox, webpage, firefox-3.6, mht

On Internet Explorer, there is an option to save a web page as single web page (`.mht`). I can't see that option on Firefox.

How can I save a web page as single web page on Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an official support page for my problem:

> ### [MAFF and MHT support for Firefox](http://maf.mozdev.org/)
>
> **MAFF** is a single-file format that contains one or more web pages.
>   **MHT** is usually created by Internet Explorer or other browsers. The
>   Mozilla Archive Format add-on can read
>   and create MHT files, with excellent
>   compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

there's an add-on for firefox which does that.

http://www.unmht.org/unmht/en_index.html